# working with jQuery sortable and draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've built a sortable and connected with a draggable list just like plenty of others. However, if I don't use the `clone` helper on the draggable, the drag placeholder gets offset and the placement of it gets messed up. But when I do use `clone`, the cloned item doesn't have the item ID, which I was intending to pass back to the server on `stop`.

What's the best way to handle this? Should I use a `data` element on the `li` to store the 'value' of the `li`?

Second questions-- on `stop` I want to remove a class from the dropped element, and add a new class. However I can't figure out how to reference this element. `this` doesn't work, and the other objects passed in to the `stop` event are `ui` and `event`-- `ui.helper` looked like it may have the info I need, but this doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks!

Fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/37tdS/

Comment: You could continue to use `clone` but when you `start` the drag, copy the *ID* to a `data()` property attached to the object being dragged. On the second question, why not use the `drop` event on the `droppable` container to reference the dropped element via `$(this)`?

Comment: @DevlshOne-- thanks, you put me on the right track. I ended up using `update` rather than the `drop` event so I could apply styles to the cloned element rather than the original. New fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/37tdS/6/

Comment: Glad you got it worked out!